# Why can't I see the topology information on the dlux.topology page when I connect the ODL controller to the mininet?

Tags: karaf, sdn, opendaylight, openflow

Why can't I see the topology information on the dlux's topology page when I connect the ODL controller to the mininet?

ODL's specific information:

```
version: distribution-karaf-0.6.0-Carbon or karaf-0.8.1
installed features: odl-openflowplugin-service-rest & odl-dluxapp-yangman & odl-dluxapps-topology
```

The mininet's start order:

```
sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=192.168.11.1
```

When I open 127.0.0.1:8181/index.html. I don't see the switch in the dlux topology page. But when I use karaf-0.8.3 for similar operations, I can see a switch.

More informations may help: I used the controller karaf-0.8.1 to capture the package of the openflow protocol, but I can only catch hello, port status and echo. However, when I use the controller karaf-0.8.3, I can catch hello, port status, feature_request, many multipart_request and role_request.

Does anybody know how to solve it? THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Despite many calls for help from the upstream community, no one stepped up to support and maintain DLUX. By the time Oxygen (the 8.x version you mention) came out, it hadn't been well-maintained for at least a year. So tl;dr it's likely there are bugs and you're better off to just avoid DLUX, use REST.